# Is it possible that any life on earth could evolve to live off a liquid which is not water?

Tags: science-based, biology, evolution

Is it possible that any life on earth could evolve to live off a liquid which is not water? Something like oil or some other natural liquid?

Comment: One of the functions of water is to be a solvent. Maybe if a lifeform is resistant to ethanol or some other alcohol, that could be used instead? I don't know how plausible this is, so I will refrain from answering.

Comment: These questions are tricky to answer because "life" does not have a clear-cut answer.  Whether life could evolve without water is very dependent on what your personal definition for "life" is.

Comment: Are you asking if life existing on Earth could adapt to completely different medium, or if another [abiogenesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abiogenesis) could have happened in other medium?

Comment: @kutschkem If this were possible, the Irish would have evolved this already... :)

Comment: WC Fields researched this question quite intensively during his spiritual journey thru life.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Water can be substituted with liquid [Ammonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_types_of_biochemistry#Ammonia) (NH3) which has many chemical properties which are similar to water and can fulfill most of the roles which are usually fulfilled by water in organic chemistry.

Ammonia is liquid between -80° C and -30° C. So an ammonia-based biosphere would only be possible on worlds much colder than Earth (or with an atmosphere with a much higher pressure).

However, Ammonia has a problem: It is flammable. When there would be an ocean of Ammonia on a planet with an oxygen atmosphere (and don't think you can get rid of oxygen that easily), one spark would ignite it. Burning ammonia becomes nitrogen and water-ice. So most larger ammonia lakes would likely be below an ice layer.

Comment: If life was evolving from Ammonia, would there necessarily be plants producing large amounts of Oxygen?  Free Oxygen doesn't like to exist by itself and tends to Oxidize something.

Comment: @bowlturner Likely yes. Replacing oxygen with something else would be another huge change in organic chemistry. Exploring whether or not this might be possible would be stuff for another question. However, you will always need some oxidizing agent which likely would also oxidize ammonia.

Comment: I won't argue that, but ammonia is very different from water.  I guess my point was if something isn't producing O2 then some other chemistry will need to be happening.

Comment: @bowlturner - questions like this make me wonder if the earth started as ammonia and oxygen and became the nitrogen water mix that we have today by this process.  Any oxygen on this planet would ultimately result in a atmosphere not unlike earth, no?

Comment: @Twelfth my chemistry is too rusty to have an answer for that.

Comment: cant methane work too? nasa has been theorizing if it can work for years now.

Answer (score 8):

No, water based life could not swap solvents to ammonia or hydrocarbon.  It's far to big of a jump to make.  The closest that might happen would be that chemicals from water based biology might be part of biogenesis in a different medium.  This would require dumping a significant mass of water based biomatter into an environment with large amounts of liquid ammonia or methane.

Comment: but there are archaea on earth which have evolved to use methane instead of water

Comment: @zackit I can find plenty of references to archaea producing methane but not to archaea that use methane as a solvent within which their core biochemistry occurs.  Do you have a source you can point to?

Answer (score -1):

An organism that doesn't require water is called a xerophile. Endoliths -- http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Endolith are one example. They live off iron, potassium, or sulfur. Pretty sure there are lots of bacteria that don't metabolize water. And we've witnessed bacteria develop entirely new metabollic pathways. Nylonaise for instance, evolved to metabolize nylon, Escherichia coli evolved a metabolic pathway for ethylene glycol: pathway http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6336729

Comment: Metabolize == food, not water. Make sense?

Comment: they do reqire water. -1

Comment: Yes, xerophiles can live with little water, but not with no water at all.